# discord.py how could I create a spontaneous response to a random message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot that, essentially, is really mean to the user. I'm trying to make it have a random chance of reading your message back to you and then insulting you. How would I go about detecting whenever a new message is sent and then rolling a random number, which, if met, will take the contents of the message just sent and copy it into its own message?

I'm not very good at describing, but here's how I'd want it to play out:
You could be having a normal conversation and at any given time, completely unprovoked, the bot will mimick you:

Person 1: haha you stink

Person 2: cmon man, be nice

Bot: "cmon man, be nice" haha do you know how dumb you sound?

- Except "cmon man" could be literally any message sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, maybe? Here's a sample code of how this could work with some notes attached

```
import random

@client.event # client or bot or whatever you're using
async def on_message(message): # on message send event
     dice_roll = random.randint(# number one, # number two)
     if dice_roll == # your go ahead number:
         await message.channel.send(f'/'{message}/' your taunting message')
         await client.process_commands(message)
     else:
         # whatever you want to do if go ahead number isnt rolled
         await client.process_commands(message)
```

I tried to leave some open space and notes so you could adapt it to your code. Hope this helps